# enum or class name as identifier

Tags: c#, class, enums

I have an enum which contains all the blocks there are:

```
enum BlockType
{
   Grass, Dirt, Stone
}
```

Let's say I have an abstract `Block` class:

```
abstract class Block
{
   public Position position;
   public BlockType type;
}
```

And all of the blocks continue like this:

```
class Grass : Block
{
   ...
}
```

I can now easially check if a block is grass:
`if (block.type == BlockType.Grass)`

But I can also do this: `if (block is Grass)`
Which means I don't need to have that variable, saving RAM.

What would be better: identifying the block the enum way or the class way?

Comment: do you want to do more with the `Grass` type? I mean add special methods or properties to it? If so you can inherit from the abstract `Block` class. If you just want to identify the type then use enum.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand why would you even need an additional enum to check types of your objects.

Comment: Remember that for `class GrassyKnoll : Grass` then `GrassyKnoll is Grass`

Comment: If you ever want to use a `switch` or `if` statement to branch on the type of the Block then an enum is more efficient (or less verbose), even though the enum is redundant in a strict OO sense.

Comment: Do all your types behave the same or do they only share some common behaviour while also implementing some differently?

Comment: Or you can use my library: http://genericinvoker.codeplex.com - but I do not recommend it to you. Just showing other possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to never know the type of the block from the outside. Let's say you want to draw Grass blocks green and Stone blocks grey. You could request the type from the block and then determine the color depending on the type, but it is better to call `block.getColor`, or even `block.draw`. The block itself knows what it is, obviously, so it can return the correct color or draw itself in the correct color.

Apart from this, using class names is definitely better than using enums. I would dispose of the whole enum. Then, if you want to add a class you don't have to also update the enum.

Comment: I've never thought about that that way. You don't need to know what block it is, the block itself knows it!